# Difference between proto package and java_package in gRPC proto file?

Tags: grpc, grpc-java, protobuf-java

I am a beginner to gRPC.
.proto file has package and option java_package fields.
As per my understanding, java_pacakge is a more sophisticated field to put the generated code .

1.My question is do we need to define pacakge if we already defined
java_package?

2.Second question is, I'm enabling retry through service config. In
retry config file service name should  be pkg.ServiceName , so if I
don't have package defined, can I simply ignore package name  and
just define service  name in retry config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do we need to define package if we already defined java_package?

Absolutely. `package` is the wire-level namespacing used for gRPC methods and for messages included in Anys. It would also be used for non-Java languages.

You should always have `package`, and often you will have `java_package`. The main reason for both is that Java uses reverse DNS for its namespacing whereas protobuf does not. For example, `google.rpc` is a protobuf package, but `com.google.rpc` would be the equivalent Java package, to follow the normal conventions.

> In retry config file service name should be pkg.ServiceName , so if I don't have package defined, can I simply ignore package name?

Yes, you would simply have `ServiceName` because there is no package. However, that means your service could collide with anyone else that also chooses not to have a package. Not having a package is possible, but is discouraged in the same way not having a Java package is possible but discouraged.